# ORA-00979 : Another not a GROUP BY expression

Tags: oracle, plsql, group-by, sql-insert

Probably a similar question have already been answered, but I couldn't find it.

My query below throw an ORA-00979 error:

```
begin
DELETE FROM TMP_MY_CHART1;
INSERT INTO TMP_MY_CHART1 (
    SELECT to_number (t.yyyy) as annee ,t.total
    FROM (
        SELECT to_char(fi.RSX_DATDERNMAJ, 'YYYY') as yyyy , COUNT(1) as total
        FROM FI_RESEAU fi
        WHERE fi.RSX_TYPLIC = 'TMP'
        GROUP BY to_char(fi.RSX_DATDERNMAJ, 'YYYY')
    ) t
);
end;
```

The TMP_MY_CHART1 table has only two columns, annee and total, both are of the type number.

The top SELECT alone works ok :

```
SELECT to_number (t.yyyy) as annee ,t.total
FROM (
    SELECT to_char(fi.RSX_DATDERNMAJ, 'YYYY') as yyyy , COUNT(1) as total
    FROM FI_RESEAU fi
    WHERE fi.RSX_TYPLIC = 'TMP'
    GROUP BY to_char(fi.RSX_DATDERNMAJ, 'YYYY')
) t
;
```

but when I precede with INSERT INTO, it throw an error.

Any help please ?

Comment: I don't get an error in any Oracle version I've tested. Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/1rfwdOdp

Comment: Really ... that strange, I am using SQLDev

Comment: The tool you are using shouldn't matter. Sorry, I have no idea where the problem may lie.

Comment: Thanks any way for spending time to answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is *something* about SQL Developer, I think.

Because, your code works OK in SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> begin
  2  DELETE FROM TMP_MY_CHART1;
  3  INSERT INTO TMP_MY_CHART1 (
  4      SELECT to_number (t.yyyy) as annee ,t.total
  5      FROM (
  6          SELECT to_char(fi.RSX_DATDERNMAJ, 'YYYY') as yyyy , COUNT(1) as total
  7          FROM FI_RESEAU fi
  8          WHERE fi.RSX_TYPLIC = 'TMP'
  9          GROUP BY to_char(fi.RSX_DATDERNMAJ, 'YYYY')
 10      ) t
 11  );
 12  end;
 13  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

There's nothing obviously wrong about it; lucky you, as there are different ways to do the same thing, rewrite it to e.g. this, which works in SQL Developer as well:

```
SQL> begin
  2    delete from tmp_my_chart1;
  3    insert into tmp_my_chart1
  4      select extract(year from rsx_datdernmaj), count(*)
  5      from fi_reseau
  6      where rsx_typlic = 'TMP'
  7      group by extract(year from rsx_datdernmaj);
  8  end;
  9  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

[image]